# Change img class attribute on error

Tags: angular

My HTML:

```
<img *ngIf="someCondition" src="assets/images/type-{{object.plastic}}.png" id="type_img" class="select-img" alt="Plastic" onError="console.log(this.class)"/>
```

I am trying to change the class of `img` attribute if the image is not found. When I console out `this.class`, I get `undefined` but if i try with `this.src` I get the `src` value. How can I change the class?

Comment: You don't you use the NgClass property from Angular? https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.className` instead. 
There is not 'class' property on DOM Element in JS.

Also remember that `className` property contains all the classes of element separated by space.

For example, 
HTML:

```
<button id="my-btn" class="btn btn-big btn-red"></button>
```

JS:

```
let myBtn = document.getElementById('my-btn');
console.log(myBtn.className); // "btn btn-big btn-red"
```

*Also, please note, that if you are using Angular or AngularJS you should better take a look on `ngClass` [directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and use it when possible.*

Comment: Thanks! ... gonna jump out the window.

Comment: Just saw your edit. How do I use `ngClass` in conjunction with checking the image load?

Comment: ngClass directive can apply particular classes to the element depending on some conditions, for example truthy or falsy variable.
You can set some variable to false, for example, when error occures. And use that variable in the ngClass directive. 
Check official docs for further examples.